# WordPress is not creating table in database after activating plugin,

Tags: database, sql

I struggled with this a long time! Can anyone help me?
My plugin is not creating a database table once activated. The following code is in the main plugin file.

```
function woocq_activate() {

    global $wpdb;

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'woocq';

    $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
        message TEXT NOT NULL,
        question_id INT NOT NULL,
        product_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
        timestamp BIGINT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (id)
    );";

    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
    dbDelta( $sql );
    
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'woocq_activate' );
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Turn on debugging and check your error logs. https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG